# Having trouble using winpcap to write DLT_USER0 captures

Tags: c++, libpcap, winpcap

I'm making a C++ program using MINGW that uses the Winpcap library to save BTLE packets into a PCAP file.

I'm trying to open a PCAP file using the DLT_USER0 link layer type.

I can open DLT_USER0 using the call to pcap_open_dead() but pcap_dump_open() is complaining that it doesn't know the corresponding link type.

I get the following message after calling pcap_geterr():

```
     out-dump.pcap: link-layer type -1 isn't supported in savefiles
```

Here's my code below.

```
#define OUT_FILENAME "out-dump.pcap"

pcap_t *pcap_dumpfile;  // Descriptor of an open capture instance
pcap_dumper_t *dumper;  // libpcap savefile descriptor"

// pcap_open_dead() creates a pcap_t structure to use when 
// calling other functions in libpacp
pcap_dumpfile = pcap_open_dead(DLT_USER0, 128);

// Check if pcap_dumpfile was created. If it was not it will return a NULL
if (NULL == pcap_dumpfile)
{
    cout << "\npcap_open_dead() FAILED!!!" << endl;
}
else
{
    // Open a save file to write to!
    dumper = pcap_dump_open(pcap_dumpfile, OUT_FILENAME);

    pcap_dump_flush(dumper);

    // Check if the dumper was created
    if (NULL == dumper)
    {
        // Printout the FAIL status
        cout << "\npcap_dump_open() FAILED!!!" << endl;

        // Printout the PCAP Error
        cout << "\n" << pcap_geterr(pcap_dumpfile) << endl;

        // Close the pcap_dumpfile and deallocate it's resources
        pcap_close(pcap_dumpfile);
    }
}
```

I'm using the WinPcap 4.1.2 Developer's Pack to build my C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, that's a bug in WinPcap 4.1.2.

Hopefully, a future release of WinPcap will be based on a later version of libpcap in which the bug is fixed.